# For any symbol, how can I get the full context-qualified name of the symbol as a string?

Tags: contexts, variable

I'd like to have a function, whether built-in or not, that when given a symbol, whether bound to a value or not, returns a string giving the context and name of the symbol.

Example: `f[a]` returns `` "Global`a" ``

Example: `` f[Developer`$MaxMachineInteger] `` returns `` "Developer`$MaxMachineInteger" ``

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works, though it'd be nicer to have a built-in way to do it:

```
SetAttributes[fullyQualifiedName, {HoldAll, Listable}];
fullyQualifiedName[a_] := Context[a] <> SymbolName[Unevaluated@a]
```

Some demonstrations:

```
In[4]:= fullyQualifiedName[a]

Out[4]= "Global`a"

In[5]:= foo = 3

Out[5]= 3

In[6]:= fullyQualifiedName[foo]

Out[6]= "Global`foo"

In[7]:= fullyQualifiedName[Plot]

Out[7]= "System`Plot"

In[9]:= fullyQualifiedName[Developer`$MaxMachineInteger]

Out[9]= "Developer`$MaxMachineInteger"
```

Comment: I bit of poking around reveals that (at least in v7) the system function `Information` also uses `Context` therefore I suppose this is the canonical method.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Sadly no, Information only prints things, it doesn't return a string. I want to use this programmatically, not interactively.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear.  What I mean is `Information` uses basically the same method you posted above, so I doubt a "better" way exists or the developers would have used it.  I think your answer is the canonical method.

Comment: You didn't have your employer information in your profile when I wrote the comment above and now it looks quite silly.  Oh well.

Comment: Well, it's a useful data point.

Answer (score 11):

This is a variation of [Leonid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin)'s answer that avoids the dependence on a context like `` "Test`" `` that must be empty:

```
SetAttributes[fq, {Listable, HoldAll}];

fq[sym_] := Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = True},ToString[Unevaluated[sym]]]

fq[{fq, Print, Developer`$MaxMachineInteger}]

(* {"Global`fq", "System`Print", "Developer`$MaxMachineInteger"} *)
```

Comment: Very useful! Would love to see stuff like that documented instead of additional famous person curves.

Answer (score 9):

Here is an alternative:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll];
f[a_Symbol] :=      
   Block[{$ContextPath = {"Test`"}, $Context = "Test`"},
      ToString[Unevaluated@a]
   ];
```

It is based on the way *Mathematica* treats short and long names depending on the current settings of `$Context` and `$ContextPath`. The context `` "Test`" `` must not exist for it to be fully bulletproof (it will produce short names for symbols in `` "Test`" `` otherwise), you can use some random string for it. The function produces the same output as yours. You can make it `Listable` as well, but for speed, it may be better to add a special rule for a list of symbols, so that the context is changed only once.

Comment: Yes, that's interesting. Maybe a UniqueContext[], a counterpart to Unique, could help eliminate the dependence on Test`.

Comment: @JoelKlein Having `UniqueContext[]` would be quite handy, and not only for this problem. It would have to be efficient, however (e.g. `Contexts[]` can be quite slow).

Comment: @JoelKlein A `UniqueContext[]` would certainly help [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112695/can-a-package-append-its-context-to-distributedcontexts). I take it it hasn't been implemented, though.