# FullForm with context for each symbol?

Tags: contexts, parsing

`FullForm` strips the context for any symbol that can be found on the `Append[$ContextPath, $Context]`: `` FullForm[System`List] `` is displayed `List`, but I would like to get `` System`List `` for debugging and learning purposes.

I tried `$ContextPath = {}` but then the whole front-end stops working [1].

Is there another way besides

```
Hold[...] /. x_Symbol :> (Context@x <> SymbolName@Unevaluated@x)
```

Is there any case where this would not work?

---

[1] I find it strange that the internal code of the *FrontEnd* relies on the "usability features" `$Context` and `$ContextPath`. Why doesn't it use the full symbol names for any code it uses (or produces)? IMO `$ContextPath = {}` should hurt *you* (having to type the full name of any symbols not in `$Context`), but not the system. If it really needs `` System` `` to operate properly, it should not allow setting `$ContextPath = {}` just like it is not allowed to set `$Context` to something invalid.

[2] Note that `Context` has `HoldFirst` while `SymbolName` doesn't, hence the `Unevaluated`.

Comment: Related: [(1742)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1742/121), [(17916)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17916/121)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. To not mess with `$ContextPath` you can `Block` it just for that evaluation.
   e.g. `Block[{$ContextPath = {}}, ...]`.

   But we don't want to do that for the evaluation, input for `FullForm` should be evaluated freely and only the result should be returned with full symbols' names.

   To achieve that you should know:
2. `$ContextPath` and `$Context` affect the typesetting. `MakeBoxes` will strip those contexts from an evaluated `FullForm`.

So, to deal with `2` we have to perform `MakeBoxes` on our rules (local contexts values) and order that to not be touched by `MakeBoxes` anymore (`RawBoxes`):

```
Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "other`"}
   ,
   RawBoxes @ ToBoxes @ FullForm @ {x, 1}
]
```

> ```
> System`List[Global`x,1]
> ```

It is very convenient when we want to "toggle a visibility" of specific contexts:

```
Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`"}, ...
```

> ```
>  List[Global`x,1]
> ```

Comment: Very clever! :^)

Answer (score 2):

Based on Kuba's idea, this may also work:

```
RawBoxes@MakeBoxes[FullForm[p + q]] /. 
   x_String :> Context[Evaluate@Symbol@x] <> Last@StringSplit[x, "`"] /; NameQ[x]
```