# Import package with correct symbol contexts

Tags: import, packages, expression-manipulation, contexts

I am looking to do some automated analysis on packages, e.g. automatically check for common mistakes.  Mathematica makes it relatively easy to manipulate code as data, and `Import` can get the expressions from a package, so I was hoping that this would be possible.

The biggest obstacle so far is that having the proper context for each symbol is often critical, and `Import` doesn't handle this.

**Is there an existing solution that can infer the correct context of each symbol when importing a package?**

Example:

```
code = "
 BeginPackage[\"Foo`\"]
 MyFoo::usage = \"MyFoo[] is a function\";
 Begin[\"`Private`\"]

 foo[] := 3 (* helper function *)
 MyFoo[] := foo[]^2 (* my function *)

 End[]
 EndPackage[]
 ";

ImportString[code, "HeldExpressions"]
```

> ```
> {HoldComplete[BeginPackage["Foo`"]], 
>  HoldComplete[MyFoo::usage = "MyFoo[] is a function";], 
>  HoldComplete[Begin["`Private`"]],
>  HoldComplete[foo[] := 3], 
>  HoldComplete[MyFoo[] := foo[]^2],
>  HoldComplete[End[]], 
>  HoldComplete[EndPackage[]]}
> ```

I want `` HoldComplete[Foo`MyFoo::usage = "MyFoo[] is a function";] ``, `` HoldComplete[Foo`Private`foo[] := 3] ``, etc.

I know that creating something that always works is plainly impossible without rewriting the evaluator itself.  What I am hoping for is something that works well enough to be practically useful and handles most common package structures.  And something that hopefully already exists.

Comment: If you want your analysis to be completely static, you need to have all the source files for dependencies and their dependencies available as well. Is that the case for your indented use cases of this?

Comment: @Leonid Yes, but as a start I would be content with a single-file solution.  Also, the analysis doesn't need to be completely static in the sense that if there is a way to record the expressions from the package *while the package is being loaded*, that is fine, even preferable.  But I don't think it's possible.  Is there some undocumented way to hook into the parser?  Also, I realize that such a tool must to some extent be influenced by the current environment and what symbols already exists in contexts in the context path.

Comment: @Szabolcs so at the end it can load the package except of importing it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
code = "
  BeginPackage[\"Foo`\"]
  MyFoo::usage = \"MyFoo[] is a function\";
  Begin[\"`Private`\"]

  foo[] := 3 (* helper function *)
  MyFoo[] := foo[]^2 (* my function *)
 bar[]:=DynamicModule[{x},{Dynamic[x],x}];

  End[]
  EndPackage[]
  "
```

*Added a line with `DynamicModule` to show obstacles.*

1. #### Printing with full names:

   - **As Boxes**

     We can use [FullForm with context for each symbol?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119922/5478) to show contexts in read expressions representations.

     But it will not prevent expressions with `FormatValues` (`MakeBoxes` upvalues) from being applied, e.g.

     ```
     Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "System`"}, 
      RawBoxes@ToBoxes@Dynamic[x]
     ]
     ```

     > ```
     > x  (*DynamicBox[...]*)
     > ```

     There is `DynamicBox` inside but one would expect `` Dynamic[Global`x] `` anyway.

     So let's use code from [Unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/5478)

     ```
      ToInputFormBoxes = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
        FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[#, True]
      ][[1, 1]] &;

      withContext = Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "System`"}, 
        RawBoxes @ ToInputFormBoxes @ ToString[ #, InputForm ]
      ] &;

      withContext[Dynamic[x]]
     ```

     > ```
     >  Dynamic[Global`x]
     > ```
   - As a String

     Alternatively, one just use `ToString` and not care but I prefer boxes as syntax highlighting is respected, etc.

     ```
     Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "System`"}, 
       ToString @ Dynamic[x]
     ]
     ```

     > "Dynamic[Global`x]"
2. #### Reading package step by step

   Now we are ready we can read expression by expression and return formatted output. The key is an ability of `Read` to do `Read[..., Hold[Expression]]`.

   This example is created for a string but `StringToStream` can be replaced with `OpenRead`.

   ```
   GetAndRead[code_String] := Module[{str, expr, list},
     str = StringToStream[code];
     list = Reap @ While[
        expr = Read[str, HoldComplete[Expression]]; 
        expr =!= EndOfFile
        ,
        Sow[ Interpretation @@ {withContext[expr], expr} ];
        ReleaseHold[expr];
     ];
     Close[str];
     list[[-1, 1]]
   ]

   GetAndRead[code] // Column
   ```

   [image]

Comment: I did not know `Read[..., Hold[Expression]]`.  This is really the key to the solution.

Comment: This is much better than what I expected to be possible. Do you foresee any problems?

Comment: `Read[..., HoldComplete[Expression]]` is safer.

Comment: @Szabolcs I didn't know `Read[..., HoldComplete[Expression]]` as only `Hold` example is shown in details of `Read`.

Comment: Actually, even `Read[..., f[Number]]` works.  `f` is auto-applied.  This is documented as "You can use Read to get objects to insert into any expression structure, not necessarily a list."  "List" here refers to the `{...}` in `Read[..., {Number, Number}]`.  The point is that `Read[..., f[Number, Number]]` is valid too, and so is `Read[..., f[g[Number], h[Number]]` or any other combination.  I did not get this from that one sentence I quoted above.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about FormatValues or *displaying* these expressions at this moment.  Just having them in a `HoldComplete` is sufficient.

Comment: @Szabolcs T.G. uses something very similar in `JLink.m` to parse symbols exported to ``Package` `` subcontext so I think it is safe enough.

Comment: My ultimate use case for this is creating a useful and extensible [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) for Mathematica.

Comment: same thing is also used in the MUnit package, which is delivered as source code...