# Can Read[] apply a custom function automatically to the read values?

Tags: import, streams, parsing

`Read[stream, Number]` will return a single read number.  We can use a number of standard, documented [types](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Read.html) instead of `Number`, such as `String`, `Expression`, `Real`, etc.

Is it possible to get `Read` to immediately apply a function to the expression that was just read, similarly to how [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) applies its third argument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes!  This is documented under [Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Read.html):

> You can use Read to get objects to insert into any expression structure, not necessarily a list.  Example: `Read[stream,Hold[Expression]]` gets an expression and places it inside `Hold`.

What this means is that we can use any compound expression as the second argument of `Read`.  Any type names (such as `Number`, `Real`, `Expression`, etc.) that appear in this compound expression will be replaced by the values that are read.

Suppose we have an input file containing

```
1 2 3+4
```

Then we can read and process the data at the same time this way:

```
Read[str, Number]  -->  1      read one number

Read[str, {Number, Number}]  -->  {1, 2}     read two numbers

Read[str, f[Number, Number]]  -->  f[1, 2]   read two numbers and wrap them in f instead of List

Read[str, {{Number, Number}, Expression}]  -->  {{1, 2}, 7}    two numbers and an expression

Read[str, {{Number, Number}, Hold[Expression]}  --> {{1, 2}, Hold[3+4]}    two numbers and a held expression
```

The two most prominent applications are the ones shown in the documentation:

- Read values grouped into lists, `Read[..., {Number, Number, Number}]`
- Read held expressions using `Read[..., HoldComplete[Expression]]`.  The expression is inserted into `HoldComplete` before evaluation.

Comment: I posted this because I did not know about this feature and even after reading the documentation it took me a while to get the point.  I thought others will find it useful.  Thanks to @Kuba [for showing](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124670/12) `Read[..., Hold[Expression]]`!