# Map every second element of a list

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I've loaded a CSV:

```
Colors = Import[
  "d:\\bitbucket\\diversity\\data\\nlcd\\nlcd-colors.csv", "CSV"]
{{0., " 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000"}, {11., 
  " 0.27843137255 0.41960784314 0.62745098039"}, {12., 
  " 0.81960784314 0.86666666667 0.97647058824"}, {21., 
  " 0.86666666667 0.78823529412 0.78823529412"}, {22., 
  " 0.84705882353 0.57647058824 0.50980392157"}}
```

And I would like this:

```
{{0., RGBColor[0.00000000000,0.00000000000,0.00000000000]}, {11., 
  RGBColor[0.27843137255,0.41960784314,0.62745098039]}, {12., 
  RGBColor[0.81960784314,0.86666666667,0.97647058824]}, {21., 
  RGBColor[0.86666666667,0.78823529412,0.78823529412]}, {22., 
  RGBColor[0.84705882353,0.57647058824,0.50980392157]}}
```

Comment: `Flatten[{First[#], 
    RGBColor @@@ ToExpression[StringSplit[Rest[#]]]}] & /@ Colors`

Comment: {#[[1]], RGBColor @@ (ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#[[2]]])} & /@Colors

Comment: Or use `MapAt`: `MapAt[RGBColor @@ ToExpression[StringSplit[#]] &, Colors, {All, 2}]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Edit

Ok, so an incorrect answer producing arrays like:

```
{{"0.", RGBColor["0.00000000000", "0.00000000000", "0.00000000000"]}}
```

received +12 and an accept. Let's correct it though:

```
Activate @ ReadList[
  file
, {Number, RGBColor[Inactive[ToExpression][Word], Number, Number]}
, WordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", ","}
]
```

> ```
> {{0., RGBColor[0., 0., 0.]}, ...}
> ```

---

*Original answer*

Let's try to get those numbers directly from the file:

```
ReadList[
  file
, {Word, RGBColor[Word, Word, Word]}
, WordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", ","}
]
```

To learn what is going on please read:

[Can Read[] apply a custom function automatically to the read values?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124675/5478)

Comment: Thanks, for all the answers, I would accept more if I could.

Comment: I think your original answer was *not* the same as the one under *Original answer*; I did check the original answer and it *did* work; my up-vote was motivated by the use of `ReadList`; I think you are onto something though

Comment: @user42582 my very first answer was: `{#, RGBColor[##2]} & @@@ ReadList[  file, ConstantArray[Word, 4], WordSeparators -> {"\t", " ", ","}]` but I don't think it works like it should. I was too fast and didn't noticed that the result was containing strings instead of numbers.

Answer (score 10):

If we define:

```
rgb[s_] := RGBColor @@ StringReplace[s, Whitespace~~n:NumberString :> ToExpression[n]]
```

then we can write any of the following expressions:

```
MapAt[rgb, Colors, {All, 2}]

Colors // Query[All, {2 -> rgb}]

ReplacePart[Colors, {i_, 2} :> rgb[Colors[[i, 2]]]]
```

to obtain:

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

Here is your list:

```
lst = {{0., " 0.00000000000 0.00000000000 0.00000000000"}, {11., 
   " 0.27843137255 0.41960784314 0.62745098039"}, {12., 
   " 0.81960784314 0.86666666667 0.97647058824"}, {21., 
   " 0.86666666667 0.78823529412 0.78823529412"}, {22., 
   " 0.84705882353 0.57647058824 0.50980392157"}};
```

Try this:

```
{#[[1]], RGBColor[Map[ToExpression, StringSplit[#[[2]]]]]} & /@ lst

(*  {{0., RGBColor[{0., 0., 0.}]}, {11., 
  RGBColor[{0.27843137255, 0.41960784314, 0.62745098039}]}, {12., 
  RGBColor[{0.81960784314, 0.86666666667, 0.97647058824}]}, {21., 
  RGBColor[{0.86666666667, 0.78823529412, 0.78823529412}]}, {22., 
  RGBColor[{0.84705882353, 0.57647058824, 0.50980392157}]}}   *)
```

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 5):

You could also try

```
 MapAt[
   Apply[RGBColor,First@ImportString[#, "Table"]] &, Colors, {All, 2}]
```

which outputs

> ```
>  {
>    {0., RGBColor[0., 0., 0.]}, 
>    {11.,RGBColor[0.27843137255, 0.41960784314, 0.62745098039]}, 
>    {12., RGBColor[0.81960784314, 0.86666666667, 0.97647058824]}, 
>    {21., RGBColor[0.86666666667, 0.78823529412, 0.78823529412]}, 
>    {22., RGBColor[0.84705882353, 0.57647058824, 0.50980392157]}
>   }
> ```

or, equivalently

[image]

Effectively, [`MapAt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html)
applies an appropriate data extracting function on the second item for *every* entry in the list `Colors`.

The function that it uses to extract the data (in this case, the *RGB* values in the strings) is `Apply[RGBColor,First@ImportString[#, "Table"]] &`.

Every string sequence of *RGB* values is first parsed, using `ImportString`; this produces a *list* of values (*not* a string, anymore).

Each list of values is then, in turn, transformed to an `RGBColor` by replacing their head of `List` with the appropriate `RGBColor` head (this is what the `Apply[RGBColor,<>]` portion of the code does).

Answer (score 4):

This way is quite simple:

```
{#1, RGBColor[ToExpression /@ StringSplit[#2]]} & @@@ Colors
```

It is almost the same as k_v's comment except I use `#1` and `#2` instead of `#[[1]]` and `#[[2]]`, and I use `@@@` instead of `@@`.

`a @@@ b` is shorthand for `Apply[a, b, {1}]`, e.g. `f @@@ {{a, b}, {c, d}}` gives `{f[a, b], f[c, d]}`.