# Building the $Context from a stack of Begin and BeginPackage

Tags: contexts

Assume I'm reading a package file and want to know the current `$Context` while going serially through the file. I want to do this by inspecting the arguments of each `Begin` and `BeginPackage`, and by collecting all `End` and `EndPackage` to maintain a *stack* or *list* of contexts. This stack is then used to build the `$Context`.

I'm mainly interested in whether my understanding of the situation is correct, how to build the current context and in the stability of the approach. Here are some examples, starting with the most trivial one

```
p[] := Print[$Context]

BeginPackage["P`"];
Global`p[];
Begin["`Private`"];
Global`p[];
End[];
Global`p[];
EndPackage[];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Here `Begin` is used to replace the context rather than appending a sub-context

```
BeginPackage["P`"];
Global`p[];
Begin["New`"];
Global`p[];
End[];
Global`p[];
EndPackage[];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

See, that `Begin` and `BeginPackage` can be mixed up. That does influence `$ContextPath` but not how `$Context` is build up:

```
BeginPackage["P`"];
Global`p[];
Begin["`New`"];
Global`p[];
EndPackage[];
Global`p[];
End[];
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In the first example, in the most inner call to `p[]`, I would have collected `` {"P`","`Private`"} ``, in the second example `` {"P`","New`"} ``. Am I correct in the following assumptions

- A (sub-)context always needs to end in `` ` ``
- Every element in my context list that does not start with a `` ` ``, like e.g. `` P` `` starts a new context. Relative contexts like `` `Rel` `` are always appended
- every `End` or `EndPackage` drops the last element of my context-list

Finally, beside the ugly `\[Alpha]` are there any special characters allowed in a context? Would it be OK to assume the following regex for a relative context?

```
`(([a-zA-Z$]+[0-9]*)+`)+
```

Comment: About the last one" ``Begin["123`"]`` gives a tip: ``A context must consist of valid symbol names separated by and ending with ` `` and valid symbol names are in documentation somewhere.

Comment: Related: [Import package with correct symbol contexts](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124606/12).  But I assume that the answer there doesn't apply because you are going to do this in Java eventually.

Comment: `$` is also allowed in context names.

Comment: OK, so I probably can re-use my regex for Symbols which can have `$` as Szabolcs pointed out but nothing else.

Comment: I am not sure that there is such a thing as a relative context.  I *think* that ``"`foo`"`` is *immediately* expanded to ``$Context`foo` ``.  It would be better to collect ``P`Private` `` instead of ``"`Private`"`` because ``"`Private`"`` can't even be interpreted without a current value of `$Context`.  (I had to use some `"` in this comment to make the markdown converter do what I wanted.)

Comment: Inner part of the regex should be `[a-zA-Z$]+[a-zA-Z$0-9]*` I think