# Manipulating definitions while reading them with Get

Tags: import, replacement, string-manipulation, scoping

In order to read in a definition with certain parameters replaced by appropriate values I can use for example

```
Block[{a=1.1,b=2.2}, Get["file"]]
```

where `"file"` is a file containing the definitions (which contain `a` and `b` on the RHS). This works well and is fast. Now is there a way to do something similar if I want to replace a string. So basically, `Block[{"string"="bla"},Get["file"]]` (but then in a way that actually works of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get @ StringToStream @ StringReplace["\"string\"" -> "\"bla\""] @ Import["file", "Text"]
```

Alternatively you can read a package step by step like in [a/124670](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/124670/5478) but instead of:

```
Sow[ Interpretation @@ {withContext[expr], expr} ];
ReleaseHold[expr];
```

do

```
ReleaseHold[expr /. "string" -> "bla"]
```