# Why is my variable Lambda defined but not the others?

Tags: variable-definitions, symbols, contexts

I would like to understand why in the following code, my variable `Λ` is recognized by the system but not `n`.

In fact for me `Λ` shouldn't be recognized as it is defined in a function.

[image]

Comment: What does `Context["n"]` return?

Comment: Or, what does `Block[{$ContextPath = {"System`"}, $Context = "System`"}, 
 RawBoxes@ToBoxes@DownValues[qDef]]` return?

Comment: Works as expected on my Mac with v11.1.1  Try starting with a fresh kernel.

Comment: maybe the first two lines not shown are something like ``local`n ; $ContextPath = Prepend[$ContextPath,  "local`"]``  .

Comment: Posting actual code is better than posting a picture of code.

Answer (score 3):

- > I would like to understand why in the following code, my variable "Lambda" is recognized by the system but not "n".

  Not quite correct, you just showed `n` isn't in `` Global` `` context. When could it happen? That is, when could `n` not be in `` Global` `` and still be displayed as `n`?

  Whenever `n` is on `$ContextPath` or `$Context`. Those values affect typesetting, see:

  [FullForm with context for each symbol?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119922/5478)

  and check:

  ```
  PacletManager`foo;    (*PacletManaget` is loaded on startup so it is on $ContextPath*) 
  foo = 1;    
  Context @ foo
  ```

  > ```
  > "PacletManager`"
  > ```

  You need to read:

  [How symbol lookup actually works](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43381/5478)
- > in fact for me Lambda shouldn't be recognized as it is defined in a function.

  It is not defined, it is mentioned, symbols are created just by parsing input.

  Quite often common names like `n, x, i, k, foo, bar` will exists in `$ContextPath` but that won't prevent them from being scoped in different functions as it is a task for scoping constructs, your function takes care of that.

  [tutorial /  VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/VariablesInPureFunctionsAndRules.html)

  [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/559/5478)

---

Further reading:

[Context of localised (dynamic) symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/75323/5478)

[Enforcing correct variable bindings and avoiding renamings for conflicting variables in nested scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478)

[Where does a package have to be loaded?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115849/5478)